# POI set minimum decimal places

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a requirement for which I have to write a double value to Excel. The number of decimal places of the values are not fixed and I need to capture all the decimals places while setting minimum of 2 decimal places but without setting a maximum limit.

#,##0.00 would only limit the value to only 2 decimal places while a format similar to #,##0.00### would limit the decimal value to 5 places. So for a double value like 100,000,000.1234567 I will miss out on additional decimal numbers.

Can someone please suggest what may be a good way to avoid setting maximum decimal limit so that I capture the actual number without rounding/truncating it in any form? Is there a way we can avoid converting the number to a String or changing the Excel cell to be of type Text.

Comment: I think POI function cell.setCellValue(mydoublevar) puts an internal xls cell value without decimal truncating. Format mask cell.setCellStyle(stDouble) cannot be dynamic but its just for display purpose.

Comment: The excel file format stores numbers as floating points values, you might want to read up on what the means and how that works!